# Single checkbox generated with iterator not working while it is not checked

Tags: jsp, struts2

In one of my Struts2 test application, I created multiple checkboxes using iterator tag like

```
<s:iterator value="valueAddedServicesMap">
   <s:checkbox name="reportData.valueAddedServices"  id="valueAddedServices" fieldValue="%{key}" value="%{key in reportData.valueAddedServices}"/>&nbsp;<s:property value="value"/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

where valueAddedServicesMap is a map having key-value pairs like {"1", "VAS 1"}, {"2", "VAS 2"} and I have List<Long>  in action class for reportData.valueAddedServices

In case of more than one checkboxes it is working fine. It populates list in action with values associated wit selected checkboxes or keeps it null if no checkbox is selected.

It is also populating single value in case of only one checkbox to dispaly and it is selected but it gives exception while only one checkbox to display and it is not selected.

exception is like :

```
[09 May 2013 10:48:45,081] [DEBUG] unable to convert value using type converter  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter]
Unparseable number: "false" at position 0 - [unknown location]
at   com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter.convertValue(NumberConverter.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToNumber(XWorkBasicConverter.java:213)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue(XWorkConverter.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue(OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.java:39)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.XWorkTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue(XWorkTypeConverterWrapper.java:36)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter.convertValue(CollectionConverter.java:54)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToCollection(XWorkBasicConverter.java:197)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:110)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue(XWorkConverter.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue(OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.java:39)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedType(OgnlRuntime.java:1064)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedTypes(OgnlRuntime.java:1081)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedMethodAndArgs(OgnlRuntime.java:1107)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1193)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1207)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1478)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2315)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:227)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:217)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:317)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:228)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.test.app.web.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only one checkbox and it isn't checked, Struts2 (just in case) sets `false` value. 
You can customize what default value will be set by setting `setUncheckedValue` in `checkbox` interceptor configuration.

Also there is a workaround to this feature. It is to add hidden field with your checkbox name prefixed with `__checkbox_` to the form. Then it won't be single checkbox and `false` will not be submitted.

```
<s:hidden name="__checkbox_YOUR-CHECKBOX-NAME"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr ... It worked :)
I tried by adding hidden field and It worked. I will also try with setting setUncheckedValue for checkbox interceptor.

Comment: @skss: See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/checkbox-interceptor.html.