# Struts2 page not returning correct value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

I have a form with various pieces of phone information for two phones, including two checkboxes that correspond to a boolean value in my action class. The below javascript is setting the second check box automatically if the user enters two identical phone numbers.

```
if(phone1 != '' && phone1==phone2)
{
    document.getElementById("phone2Type").value = document.getElementById("phone1Type").value;
    document.getElementById("phone2Text").value = document.getElementById("phone1Text").value;
    document.getElementById("phone2Text").checked = document.getElementById("phone1Text").checked;

    if( phone2Type=='CELL' && document.getElementById('phone2Text') != null)
    {       
        document.getElementById('phone2Text').disabled=true;
    }   

    document.getElementById("phone2Type").disabled=true;    
}
```

And the jspx code to go along with it:

```
<s:checkbox id="phone1Text"
    onclick="javascript:enableTextingBox()" cssClass="phoneText"
    name="phoneInfo.phone1.textOptionSelected" fieldValue="true"
    value="phoneInfo.phone1.textOptionSelected" 
    disabled="%{!phoneInfo.phone1.textOptionEnabled  || inputFieldDisabled}" />

<s:checkbox id="phone2Text"
    onclick="javascript:enableTextingBox()" cssClass="phoneText"
    name="phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionSelected" fieldValue="true"
    value="phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionSelected" 
    disabled="%{!phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionEnabled  || inputFieldDisabled}" />
```

The problem I'm seeing is that when I use javascript to set `phone2Text` equal to `phone1Text` the corresponding boolean (`phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionSelected`) is not getting set. I'm confused because the above jspx works correctly when I forget the javascript and check the box manually.

Looking at the parameters being sent in the post method, instead I see this:

`_checkbox_phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionSelected: "true"`

What I would expect to see is:

`phoneInfo.phone2.textOptionSelected: "true"`

I'm not sure if this is a Struts2 issue or some javascript peculiarity that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16461142/1654265

Comment: Do you see that both checkboxes are checked on clicking the first one? Are you sure that you checkbox is not in disabled? Because there is an if condition in your js where you are disabling checkbox input.

Comment: Both checkboxes are checked after clicking the first one. However, the second checkbox is grayed out. I thought disabling it was just a UI effect and didn't have any bearing on whether or not it was actually returning a value.

Comment: Disabling is NOT just an ui effect. See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html.

Answer (score 1):

Aleksandr M was exactly right.

This is the line that was causing my issues:

```
document.getElementById('phone2Text').disabled=true;
```

Disabling a text box causes its value not to be sent in a POST operation.